# React Route cannot render

Tags: reactjs, routes

I ran into the error:"*Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*".I don't know how to fix it! It'd be kind of you guys to help me! Thank you so much!

This is my Layout.jsx:
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from "./Header"
import Routes from '../routes/Routes'

```
const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route render={props => (
                <div>
                    <Header {...props}/>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="main">
                            <Routes/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            )}/>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

This is my Routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Catalog from '../pages/Catalog';
import Cart from "../pages/Cart";
import Product from '../pages/Product';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/catalog:slug' component={Product}/>
            <Route path='/catalog' component={Catalog}/>
            <Route path='/cart' exact component={Cart}/>
        </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: How did you export `Home`, `Catalog`, `Cart` and `Product` components ? Are they default exports ?

Comment: yes they are all in default exports